# Send request from https to local http(s) server

Tags: javascript, rest, ssl, jetty

I try to explain our problem.

We are coding a little tool (with Java 1.8 and Jetty+Jersey) which provides a rest-server for saving data (documents, ...) on hard drive or printing documents directly.

The tool can be started/accessed on local computer (localhost) or on a different device in local network.

The problem is you can't send a request from a https-page to the local tool if it's not ssl-encrypted.

What we need is a ssl-certificate for our tool.

But the problem is we can't know on which device/ip-address our customers want to run the tool and you have to bind a domain to a ssl-certificate.

We can create ssl-certificate and bind it with (for example) tool.domain.com, but the tool can run on 127.0.0.1 as well as on 192.168.10.2 or something similar.

So my question is, is there a way to (programmatically) "bypass" this wall?

One "way" would be to add an entry to local hosts file but we want as few as possible effort for our customers and you can't set hosts entry on non rooted mobile devices.

Edit: Added some code snippets.

```
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/*");

        // vhosts
//      context.setContextPath("/*");
        context.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{
             "127.0.0.1",
             "192.168.6.195",
             "localhost",
             "tool.domain.com"
        });
```

There we add the virtual host to the jetty server. We have a self-signed certificate (for testing) for our domain.

We want to archive something like this:

[image]

Here some JS-Code for testing/visualization:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://127.0.0.1:7331/test/echo/test1111');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', 'https://tool.domain.com');
xhr.send();
```

But Chrome (and I think other browser, too) blocking the Host-Header

Comment: if it's from https, it better be to https

Comment: We want to add a ssl-certificate to our tool, but the problem is the target. The target can have each ip-address. It's hard to explain the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your own company, and your own company domain name, then this is possible.

Lets say you have `dominice-so.com`

If you created a dns entry for something like `self.dominice-so.com` to always return `127.0.0.1` then you can ship a keystore/truststore with a valid certificate for the domain name `self.dominice-so.com` in your product.

The browser should be able to connect just fine, using something like ...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://self.dominice-so.com:7331/test/echo/test1111');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', 'https://tool.domain.com');
xhr.send();
```

Its up to you to secure that keystore/truststore password so that it doesn't get into nefarious hands. (and that is out of scope of this question)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that's the problem, we don't only want 127.0.0.1 but other ip-addresses, too, like 192.168.2.50 if it's a network-pc (like a server machine). We need something with as less as possible effort for our customers.
One way would be to create a wildcard-certificate and create a subdomain for each customer with his required ip-address. But this is "much" effort for us.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to generate in-environment certificates based on a CA known to that environment (each company might have different CA rules).

Comment: We are now implementing this way. I think it's the best way. Thanks again